# Question about the assumptions in a linear regression model

Tags: regression, multiple-regression, regression-coefficients, assumptions

[image]

Above is a screenshot from *Introduction to Linear Regression* by Douglas C. We usually assume that in linear regression model $y$ has a linear relationship with the parameter, but why here the author says $y$ should have a linear relationship with the regressor $x$?

Comment: What do you mean by "a linear relationship with the parameter"? That doesn't make sense to me. Relationships are between variables. A parameter is a number.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This paragraph is a bit difficult to understand, so I'll give a small example to help unpack what it says in terms of assumptions.

Imagine that y = body fat, x1 = body weight and x2 = body height and we are interested in investigating the relationship between y and x1 and x2 for all adult males in a specific community based on a random sample of 1000 males from that community.

The linear regression model relating y to x1 and x2 can then be stated as:

```
y = beta0 + beta1*x1 + beta2*x2 + error.  (*)
```

In the context of this example, the paragraph higlighted in green in your post should be interpreted as:

1. y (body fat) is linearly related to x1 (body weight) **for all the adult males in the community who share the same body height** (that is, who have the same value for x2);
2. y (body fat) is linearly related to x2 (body height) **for all the adult males in the community who share the same body fat** (that is, who have the same value for x1).

So the assumptions are that y is linearly related to x1 for each value of x2 and y is linearly related to x2 for each value of x1.  The assumption of linearity concerns two variables (e.g., y and x1) after controlling for the effect of the other predictor variable (e.g., x2). The parameter beta1 is just a way to quantify this relationship, as it indicates how fast y changes with x1 among adult males with the same value of x2. Similarly, the parameter beta2 indicates how fast y changes with x2 among adult males with the same value of x1.

Usually we check these assumptions by plotting the residuals obtained after fitting model (*) to the data separately against each of x1 and x2. If those plots show no systematic pattern, then the assumptions are supported by the data. If one of the plots shows a systematic pattern (e.g., a quadratic pattern), that's an indication that the respective predictor has a nonlinear effect on y after controlling for the effect of the other predictor.

Comment: We support math formatting using mathjax. More information: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: I really don't have the time to learn how to usw mathjax so the above will have to do.

Answer (score 2):

Linear models make the assumption of a linear relationship because linear models estimate functions of the form $y = a + b_1 x_1 + b_2 x_2 + \cdots +b_n x_n + \text{error}$, i.e. linear functions. If you don't have a linear relationship, you need to use a different model or somehow transform $y$ and/or $x$ so that the model is linear.

Answer (score 2):

I think you are possibly confusing two different concepts. In the General Linear Model, we model the response as a linear combination that is linear in parameters (e.g. B0 + B1 + B2 etc.) which is different from assuming that there exists a linear relationship between some predictor x and the response y. The assumption of this linear relationship is a fundamental assumption of the method.